# Qt(C++)上の他のアプリに何か通知したい

Tags: c++, linux, qt

Linux上で動作させるQt Creatorで作成したアプリに
他のアプリから動作完了など、何かしらの通知をする方法は無いでしょうか

今のところTCPで受け側のアプリでリスナーで適当なポートで待って
送信側のアプリで127.0.0.1のIPアドレスに何か送信しようかと思っているのですが
他に、アプリ間の通知にどんな方法があるでしょうか

Answer (score 2, accepted):

プロセス間通信は、一般的なものから Qt 専用のもの、低レベルから高レベルまでいくつか選択肢がありますね。他のアプリがすべて Qt 製なら QRemoteObject が使いやすいかなと思います。

- QTcp/UdpSocket
- QWebSocket
- QHttpServer
- QDBus*
- QRemoteObject
- QtMqtt*